# Lost in Blender space

Tags: 3d-view

I was working on something and I must've zoomed out and moved too far and now I cannot find my object I was working on.

Answer (score 3):

If you are in edit mode and you have the object selected (or part of the object) then press the period key on the num pad.

If you are in object mode you can do the same but if you have nothing selected on the object then select it in the outliner first.

Answer (score 2):

Select the object in the outliner and press the Numpad  <kbd>.</kbd> .

[image]